# Axios request from Vue app deployed on amazon S3 returns site's index

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, vue.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, axios

I deployed a "static" vue app to a public Amazon S3.

CORS configuration is the same as the default one.

After building the app I add the following line to avoid 404 error on routing:

```
<script>history.pushState({}, "Application entry", location.hash.substring(2));</script>
```

I also have a proxy configuration block:

```
proxy: {
  // proxy all requests starting with /v1
  '/v1': {
    target: 'http://some-app-deployed-on.elasticbeanstalk.com/v1',
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {
      '^/v1': '',
    },
  },
```

The vue app running locally can communicate via axios with the java backend deployed on elasticbeanstalk. On EB I've configured nginx for CORS:

```
  location /v1 {
      proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5000;
      proxy_http_version  1.1;
      add_header          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
      proxy_set_header    Connection          $connection_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
      proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
```

The request is a simple http.get

```
  axios
    .get(`/v1/endpoint/${param}`)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
```

I don't get an error (doesn't enter the `catch` block)

In `response.data` I get the content of the index page and in response.request.responseUrl I get the url of my index page.

Comment: Encountering the same issue. Since in dev mode it runs a proxy - I believe the production dist needs to be configured differently. I think this is the solution to this problem but not 100% sure : https://paweljw.github.io/2018/04/vue.js-front-end-app-part-6-deploying-to-s3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webpack proxy that was defined

```
proxy: {
  // proxy all requests starting with /v1
  '/v1': {
    target: 'http://some-app-deployed-on.elasticbeanstalk.com/v1',
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: {
      '^/v1': '',
    },
  },
```

Is only valid when running in a dev environment.

So all my requests where directed to localhost

```
axios
    .get(`/v1/endpoint/${param}`)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
```

I either need to configure a redirection in S3 / cloudfront or configure webpack so that requests `/v1/endpoint/${param}` are changed into `http://some-app-deployed-on.elasticbeanstalk.com/v1/endpoint/${param}`

I'm happy to accept any answer that helps me implement the solutions above.

EDIT:

Impossible to make the S3 webapp communicate with the back on EB...
I moved everything in the same EB

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're setting the parameters right.

Maybe something like this

```
  axios
    .get(`/v1/endpoint`, params: {
      param
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
```

Or Even

```
  axios
    .get('/v1/endpoint/' + param)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response); 
  })
```

Comment: `/v1/endpoint/${param}` === '/v1/endpoint/' + param This works when ran locally, not on amazon.